# Alterar valor do select com o Select2 JQuery no evento blur

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Estou utilizando a `Select2 JQuery` para apresentação dos selects de um sistema que estou a desenvolver. 
Tenho um campo que digito o CEP e o  select deve ter o seu valor alterado e apresentado ao usuário. 
Meu script `de teste` está atualmente assim:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cep" id="cep" >`

`<select name="estado" data-init-plugin="select2">
  <option value="AC">Acre</option>
  <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
  <option value="RO" selected>Rondônia</option>
</select>`

> $("#cep").blur(function() {
>
> $('.state option[value="AC"]').attr({ selected : "selected" });
>   });

O código acima "está funcional", o valor do `select` é alterado no back porém o valor que é apresentado ao usuário não é alterado.
Procurei na documentação da Select2, porém não encontrei a forma de alterar também o valor apresentado.

Outro teste que fiz foi alterar a classe `select2-selection__rendered` que é gerada pela Select2. Chegou a funcionar, porém se tiver mais `selects` no formulário que também usem a Select2, todos selects são alterados.

`Código alterando a classe rendered da Select2`

> $('.select2-selection__rendered').html('AC').attr("title", 'AC');

Alguém poderia informar como manipular a Select2 para este fim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algumas pesquisas e consegui resolver o problema. Na verdade a solução é simples, bastando apenas setar o método `select2()` na classe ou id que se deseja fazer a alteração do valor do `option`.

O script do protótipo funcional segue:

**Formulário:**

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cep" id="cep" >
<select name="state" id="state" data-init-plugin="select2">
  <option value="AC">Acre</option>
  <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
  <option value="RO" selected>Rondônia</option>
</select>`

**Script:**

> $("#cep").blur(function() {
>
> ```
> $('#state').val('AC').select2();
> ```
>
> });

No exemplo acima o método `select2()` faz todo o trabalho alterando o valor selecionado apresentado ao usuário, bem como seta o `option` em questão como `selected`.